# prevent ajax in uikit 3 file upload drag and drop

Tags: php, uikit

in uikit 3, when using drag and drop file upload, an ajax call happens in selecting file. it causes that form submit runs twice. when `url:` is set to php controller function, it run without submiting form. how to bind it to form submit?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the 'method' property to a function that returns false. This stops the automatic ajax request taking place.

You can then grab the files from the beforeAll event and perform a manual form submit.

```
UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {
  multiple: false,
  method: () => {return false;},
  beforeAll: function (el, files) {
    console.log('beforeAll', arguments);
    console.log('el', el);
    console.log('files', files);
  }
});
```